# Spring Boot RestTemplate List

Tags: java, json, spring

I get a response like this:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "object1":"example",
         "object2":"example",
         "object3":"example",
         "object4":"example",
         "object5":"example"
      },
      {  
         "object1":"example",
         "object2":"example",
         "object3":"example"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I wanted to Map this data to my class DTO but there I get an "error" because the DTO has no `data` field. I want it in a `List` or Array of my class.
Like:

```
List<MyClass> list = restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyClass.class);
```

I hope you know what I mean?

Comment: i think your response json is wrong, because in data[0] keys are mulltiple, which is wrong. we know json should have unique key. value can be same.

Comment: you just copy above json and put it in json editor, then you may realise what i mean

Comment: The JSON Object is valid, i just edited for example with "parma"  in reality there are other objects

Comment: i think you need to take Map<String,Object> and put your all keys in it, then put this map in to List<Object>

Comment: And your DTO contains those `object1`, `object2`, ... properties?

Comment: Yes my DTO contains the field which are in the JSON Object. The Main Problem is the "data" before the objects.    In my UserDTO it works fine cause there's no data before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach comes to mind is to convert the JSON response to a `Map<String, List<MyClass>>` and then query the map, i.e. `map.get("data")`, to get the actual `List<MyClass>`.

In order to convert the JSON response to `Map<String, List<MyClass>>`, you need to define a *Type Reference*:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, List<MyClass>>> typeRef = 
                           new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, List<MyClass>>>() {};
```

Then pass that `typeRef` to the `exchange` method like the following:

```
ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<MyClass>>> response = 
                                 restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, typeRef);
```

And finally:

```
System.out.println(response.getBody().get("data"));
```

If you're wondering why we need a type reference, consider reading Neal Gafter's post on *[Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.nl/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html)*.

**Update**: If you're going to deserialize the following schema:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "paging": {}
}
```

It's better to create a dumb container class like the following:

```
class JsonHolder {
    private List<MyClass> data;
    private Object paging; // You can use custom type too.

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Then use it in your `RestTemplate` calls:

```
JsonHolder response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, JsonHolder.class);
System.out.println(response.getData()); // prints a List<MyClass>
System.out.println(response.getPaging()); // prints an Object
```

Comment: Thanks, and how do I map this to a variable List<MyClass> ?

Comment: I can think of any solution with just `RestTemplate` being involved. I guess you should use Jackson directly and manually deserialize the JSON string to `List<MyClass>`

Comment: One more question, when I have another structure after the "data" set how do I handle this?  like http://pastebin.com/mUUm6Tib

Comment: +1 for using ParameterizedTypeReference - I started out creating a "MyClassList extends List<MyClass>" object and then doing MyClassList.class as the return type, but that is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring's ResponseEntity and array of MyClass. Below code will return an array of MyClass wrapped around

For e.g.

```
ResponseEntity<MyClass[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(
   url,
   HttpMethod.GET,
   request,
   MyClass[].class
);
... 
// response null check etc. goes here
...
MyClass[] myArr = response.getBody();
```