# How to retrieve Arraylist/list from json rest request and convert into pojo object (one of pojo variable is of list type.)

Tags: java, spring, rest, restful-url

How to retrieve `ArrayList`/`List` from JSON REST request and convert into POJO object (one of POJO variable is of list type).

// Domain class

```
@Service
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DocumentProps {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("properties")  // list variable
    private List properties;
```

// controller-class

```
@RestController
public class springteamplate {

@Autowired
    DocumentProps docprops;

@GetMapping(value = "/get")
    private  void getEmployees()
    {
        final String uri = "http://xyz";        
        docprops = RestTemplateBuild.template.getForObject(uri, DocumentProps.class);
        System.out.println(docprops.getName()); // able to retrieve name
        System.out.println(docprops.getType());  // able to retrieve type
        System.out.println(docprops.getPrpopertie());  // How to retrieve list of properties.
    }}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message or something?

Comment: First you should figure out the format properties are obtained in. Then you should create the class that describes the format.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the collection types or generic types binding using the `ParameterizedTypeReference`.

`The purpose of this class is to enable capturing and passing a generic Type.In order to capture the generic type and retain it at runtime, you need to create a subclass (ideally as anonymous inline class) as follows:`

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {};
```

For example you can reference to the [answer on question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895917/spring-boot-resttemplate-list?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Reference ParameterizedTypeReference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html)